# Image intervention resize crops top and bottom of image for some reason

Tags: php, laravel, intervention

I am having a problem with Intervention\Image resize() method.

My code is as follows:

```
$uploaded_image = Image::make($request->uploaded_image)->fit(600, null, function($constraint){
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
                $constraint->upsize();
            });
```

This as per documentation should:
1) resize the width to 600 px
2) define height of the image based on aspect ratio and the new width
3) prevent any upsizing

However, in my case, it is cropping top and bottom of the image. I am trying to handle png images if that is a tell.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a prime example of copy/pasterino, I thought I was using resize, when in reality I was using fit. All good now, no issue